# Permission denied when using kill as root

Tags: linux, java, sles, kill

I'm starting a java program as a non-privileged user that I sudo'd into, then exit the shell. Being root again I try to kill -9 the java process.
This causes a "permission denied" error.
Then I sudo again to the owning user.
Kill works as expected.
This behavior is reproducible
The environment is a virtual machine on VMWare, SLES 15.2, adopt JDK 17(though that shouldn't matter or that it is java at all).

How does that work ? As root I should be able to kill anything that isn't stuck in kernel mode.
Who is to blame for this unexpected behavior ?
(What did Poettering use as en excuse to introduce this change - just kidding ;)

Comment: as root about to use the kill command, what's the output of this command? `grep ^CapEff /proc/$$/status` . If it's not `CapEff: 000001ffffffffff` (or a near value with a lot of `f`) then something's wrong.

Comment: Hello, the output is "CapEff: 0000003fffffffff"

Comment: The value looks usual (and it does include cap_kill with `capsh --decode=0000003fffffffff`), you can ignore my comment (and look at other comments/answers for other reasons than just capabilities).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have Apparmor enabled, it can block your attempts to kill that process as non-owner.

Comment: Apparmor actually was the culprit.